# How to generate one time url to get a feedback in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, nodemailer

I am developing an app for traveling agents in an insurance company with **MEAN stack**. When a traveling agent is done with the customer, a unique URL must be emailed to the customer to get feedback. How can I generate that unique one-time URL? Or is there any other way to achieve this without creating an account for the customer? (like sending a responsive email to the customer and get feedback)

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is to 'encrypt' the query string. So lets say you want this to be a 'one-time' URL.

1. On your node server, you generate a one time string like customerID=12343&timestap=time&action=something
2. Next, on the server you would run the string through an encryption algo to encrypt the string so after it may look something like sd8753454sd548787e54sd54SDe85432 <--(this is not valid just an example but would be unreadable)
3. Now, the email you send out with the link would be something like https://example.com/validate/sd8753454sd548787e54sd54SDe85432
4. The validate route will require the string, grab that and then 'decrypt' the string. You should now have the valid string customerID=12343&timestap=time&action=something, so your DB updates etc and flag in the DB that it was clicked OR use the timestamp to check if the URL is expired

This is just one way, and when talking about encryption and how strong you need it is a huge topic, this is just one method of many ways.